# Can't get Makefile to perform complete pdflatex compilation sequence

Tags: bibtex, linux, makefile, command-line

## Folder contents

```
.
├── bibliography.bib
├── Makefile
└── template.tex
```

## `Makefile`

```
all: make_pdflatex make_glossaries make_bibtex make_pdflatex make_pdflatex
make_pdflatex:
        pdflatex template.tex
make_glossaries:
        makeglossaries template.glo
make_bibtex:
        bibtex template
```

## `bibliography.bib`

```
@misc{
  forensic_engineering,
  title={Finding answers with forensic engineering - White paper},
  author={{RoyalHaskoningDHV}},
  note={blabla},
  year={2021}
}
```

## `template.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{cite}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{NCG}
{
  name=NCG,
  description={blabla}
}

\begin{document}
  Hello world ~\cite{forensic_engineering}

\clearpage
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\clearpage
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

## Problem

The following command:

`make all | grep "pdflatex template.tex\|makeglossaries template.glo\|bibtex template"`

Generates the following output:

```
pdflatex template.tex
makeglossaries template.glo
bibtex template
```

Which shows that `make all` fails to run all five commands next to the `all` directive. I would have expected the following output:

```
pdflatex template.tex
makeglossaries template.glo
bibtex template
pdflatex template.tex
pdflatex template.tex
```

The references are not correctly updated in the pdf after I run a `make all` command, and so I must run it multiple times for the references to work.

Why does `make all` ignore the last two instances of `make_pdflatex`?

Comment: a very simple `Makefile` with a target called test what just performs `echo test` and then the target `all: test test test` shows that `make all` only runs `test` once. This question does not really seem to be LaTeX related but rather standard Linux question. BTW make, when you can use `latexmk` which more or less does your list of commands out of the box

Comment: A google on `make run target multiple times` shows that one cannot run the same target multiple times.

Comment: @daleif I wanted to avoid dedicated compilation tools in order to force myself to get to grips with how latex compilation dependencies work via a simple Makefile. Now that you mention `latexmk` I guess I can give up on that idea...

Comment: It is what is used to compile on overleaf, so I'm guessing it is good enough (`latexmk`). You could just make separate `make_pdflatex_1`, `.._2` rules...

Comment: @daleif I also saw something related to making recursive calls to `Make`  in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730883/how-can-i-get-a-makefile-target-to-be-called-multiple-times But I think that might be an overkill. I'll just stick with `latexmk` for now. Thanks.

Comment: If interested have a look at the `-pvc` option for `latexmk`. I never compile from an editor, I run something similar to `latexmk -pvc -pdf` in a terninal. This means that `latexmk` will recompile as soon as I save any changes to a file in my project. I loose the ability to jump to an error in my editor, but I can live with that.